# Accessing RDS from Elastic Beanstalk, cannot change secuirty groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I am trying to access an RDS database in a VPC from elastic beanstalk. I tried adding the vpcgroup to the the security group list for elastic beanstalk, which works for a regular ec2 instance, but when I try to do this for the elastic beanstalk security group I get the following error message:

```
Could not update your security group rules (No changes were made): You may not define rules between a VPC group and a non-VPC group
```

I have also tried adding the existing security group I use for ec2, which can access the RDS database, to the elastic beanstalk instance, but when I do that it says the security group does not exist. How can I make it so that the elastic beanstalk instance has access to my RDS database? Alternatively, what do I need to put in the config.yml file so that it starts out with my prexisting security group that already has access to the RDS database / VPC?

Answer (score 0):

Security groups are specific to a VPC. It appears that your Elastic Beanstalk environment is in EC2 classic instead of a VPC. The quick solution is to enable [Classic Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/vpc-classiclink.html). The more long-term solution is to rebuild your Elastic Beanstalk environment in your VPC.

Comment: How do you enable Classic Link in Elastic Beanstalk? I don't see an option anywhere.

Comment: @cdmckay you should really move it into a VPC instead of using classic link at this point, because you are going to be limited to older, slower, and more expensive EC2 instance types if you continue running EB outside the VPC. However if you want to continue using classic link, it looks like the best solution is to configure EB to run a command at startup to enable Classic Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067912/how-to-auto-create-a-classic-link-for-aws-eb-instances-to-vpc

Answer (score 0):

To start the instance in an existing vpc you need to add the vpc and subnet to a .config file in .ebextensions. For example:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
    option_name: VPCId
    value: vpc-IDhere

  - namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
    option_name: Subnets
    value: subnet-IDhere
```